# Use changing string as template for insert via bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I have a file that needs some inserts. The inserts are depending on existing strings within the file which i can identify with a keyword in the corresponding file. The insert itself is supposed to follow a certain line, in my example "/*HERE*/" . I usually don't work with bash so I'm a bit helpless.

I got the part for the insert to work but only unspecific for all entries and also the part for the selection:

sed -i -e '/HERE/a HelloWorld' $path

sed -e 's/.*KEY(.*)()/\1/'

Current file:

```
hello_world_12353_KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
}

abcdefg_KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3()
{

    ...

   /*HERE*/
}
```

desired outcome:

```
hello_world_12353_KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3_Addon()
}

abcdefg_KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3_Addon()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
$ sed -e '/.*KEY\(.*\)()/ { h; s//   KEY\1_Addon()/; x; }' -e '/HERE/ G' file
hello_world_12353_KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3_Addon()
}

abcdefg_KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3()
{

    ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3_Addon()
}
```

This `sed` command contains two main expressions:

1. The first triggers when a line matching `KEY...something...()` is found.  It then saves the current line into the hold space with `h`, and replaces the bit of the string before `KEY` with some pre-determined indentation, and adds the `_Addon` bit before the parentheses.  This creates the line that we later want to insert. The hold space and the editing buffer are then swapped with `x` so that the unmodified original line is outputted.
2. When a line matches `HERE` (you may want to change this to a more precise pattern like `\,/\*HERE\*,` or similar), the current content of the hold space is appended to the editing buffer with `G`, with a newline character as delimiter.

Comment: Hey, your answer does a lot already, however I'm struggling with one point or maybe two. I need to append my copied part with an additional string before the parenthesis. I tried replacing G or inserting around it but I couldn't get it running.

Comment: I got it, It needed a small change in the first part => sed -e '/.*KEY\(.*\)()/ { h; s//   KEY\1_Addon()/; x; }' -e '/HERE/ G' file

Comment: @Yamira Ah, yes, I missed that part. I will update my answer with corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { print }
    match($0,/KEY.*\(/) { new=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1) "_Addon()" }
    sub(/\/\*HERE\*\/.*/,"") { print $0 new }
' file
hello_world_12353_KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3_Addon()
}

abcdefg_KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3()
{

    ...

   /*HERE*/
   KEY_HalloHaus_8_2_3_Addon()
}
```

The above will print the newline indented by however many blanks+tabs the `/*HERE*/` string is indented.

Comment: Your code isn't working,  it produces : 

hello_world_12353_KEY_HalloWelt_1_2_3()
{

   ...

   /*HERE*/
   hello_world_12353_K_Addon()
}

Comment: @Yamira yeah, I broke it with one final edit when I posted it, sorry. I've fixed it now.